# C# abstract method and common code

Tags: c#

I want to declare some class that inherit of an abstract class with abstract method. 
**Also I want to some method in child class call a common code automatically (ie logging code)**

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract void AbstractMethod();
    public void CommonCode()
    {
        //do something
    }
}

public class ChildClass : AbstractClass
{
    public void AbstractMethod()
    {
        //automatically call CommonCode in base class
        //do something
    }
}
```

is event can help me ?

Regards

Comment: Why not just make it virtual instead? Obviously someone could still override and fail to call the method on `base`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without getting too fancy you can make the abstract method be the "guts" of what you want inheritors to do, and call that from a wrapper method on your base class.  For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    // Note that this protected since consumers won't call it directly
    protected abstract void AbstractMethod();

    // Instead, consumers will use this method which calls CommonCode
    // before the abstract method.
    public void AbstractMethodWrapper()
    {
        CommonCode();
        AbstractMethod();
    }

    public void CommonCode()
    {
        //do something
    }
}

public class ChildClass : AbstractClass
{
    protected override void AbstractMethod()
    {
        // The wrapper method in the base handles calling common code
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: @SharpC I suggest you do not edit people's answers. Always better to leave a suggestion in a comment. If you must edit it on your own, then at least leave a note in a comment, explaining your edit.

Comment: I think you mean protected override void AbstractMethod() in the ChildClass (otherwise it does not compile) but a good answer.  @Mathias Müller - not sure I agree, as I left a comment in the revision history and without my edit it does not compile, so more an essential than a minor suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: +1 for your comment - much clearer now. If you find major flaws in answers, please leave a comment to point it out or vote it down, rather than editing it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like the following (if I understand you correctly):

```
 public abstract class AbstractClass
    {
        public abstract void AbstractMethod();
        public void CommonCode()
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

    public class ChildClass : AbstractClass
    {
        public override void AbstractMethod()
        {
            //automatically call CommonCode in base class
            //do something
            base.CommonCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the CommonCode-method to be called automatically, without any extra code in the ChildClass.

Comment: Ok, this answer seems best to me then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14753944/550198

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need *interceptors*.

I'm going to suggest you PostSharp because its simplicity and how powerful is. Check for example this article:

- http://www.rhyous.com/2012/06/15/aop-implementing-try-catch-in-csharp-with-postsharp/